# How to share Family calendar with non-family member?

Tags: calendar, family-sharing

I have set up our family with iCloud, using iCloud Family Sharing.  Currently, myself and my husband define our Family and use our Family calendar for household events.

I also have a work iCloud account and would like to be able to subscribe to my home Family calendar from my work account so that I can see family events on my work calendar.  Is this possible, and if so, how can it be done (without adding my work account as a family member)?

Comment: is it a Google calendar ?

Comment: @Buscar No, it's an iCloud calendar.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution here? I'm struggling with this now.

Comment: @JimMeyer: No, I never did....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can share a Calendar with anyone in your contacts list…

Right click the calendar in the list on the left > Sharing Settings…

Start to type the name & select from matching contacts

As I recall [it's been a long time since I set mine up], they must have an iCloud account to be able to actually use it, so you'd add their mac.com, me.com or iCloud.com address.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but that doesn't work for the Family calendar (the calendar that Apple creates when you start doing Family Sharing).  It just shows an uneditable list of Family members sharing that calendar.

Comment: AH, yes - I never noticed. In that case you'd probably be better off just making a new regular calendar & sharing that - just like my G&J Shared above, which was set up long before Family Sharing came along & is still the one we use for most things, the Family one is probably still empty ;)

Comment: Hey!  It looks like with the recentish updates your suggestion now works.  The sharing list is now editable for the Family calendar just like the others.  Just click on it and a spot to add a new name pops up.

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution from my iPhone (and assuming iPad).  Open your calendar app and click "Calendars" at the bottom.  Find your iCloud family calendar and click the information icon "i".  Scroll to the bottom and you will see the option to share the calendar.  Once you share, you can copy the link.  I'm using this for a DAKBoard display and it works perfectly.

[image: Family Calendar Sharing]

Answer (score 0):

Since macOS & iOS can handle multiple iCloud accounts, you can just add your personal iCloud account to your work Mac or iPhone in addition to the work account.

You may consider to turn all other iCloud options except the calendar off in order to limit the chances of mixing them up or bringing your personal email to your work Mac.